# Call function and modify variable at the same time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Just quick question, is there a way to call a function and modify a variable at the same time?
Take this,`<button onclick="change(); var con = true">click me</button>`

```
<script>
function change() {
while (con == true) {
var x = event.clientX;
var y = event.clientY;
}
//do some more magical stuff
}
</script>
```

Basically I want to loop the while loop only if the condition is true, and do some more magical stuff at the same time, would that be possible?

Comment: Your current function will lock up the browser, are you sure you actually want this kind of loop?

Comment: Where in your code does `con === false`? Like Paul said, this is currently an infinite loop.

Comment: There is an event that I haven't mentioned, onmouseup="var con = false", that works fine I just want it to loop while the condition is true

Comment: probably, you want to use an if block instead of while?

Comment: What's that (the if block instead of while)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `while` or `for` as shown in your example code will lock up the client's browser when invoked. Consider instead using a callback-y way, e.g. with `setTimeout`

Example using `setTimeout` wrapping a function, returning a toggle function

```
function toggleableFn(fn, rate) {
    let timeout,
        run = false,
        loop;
    function looper(args) {
        if (!run) return; // double safety
        fn.apply(this, args);
        timeout = window.setTimeout(loop, rate);
    }
    return (...args) => {
        run = !run;
        if (run) {
            loop = looper.bind(this, args);
            loop();
            return true
        }
        else {
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        return false;
    };
}

var rep = toggleableFn((x, y) => console.log(x, y), 1e3);
rep('foo', 'bar'); // true
// logs "foo" "bar" every second until you toggle with `rep(); // false`
```

Comment: WOW! Thank-you, that is amazing

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<button onclick="window.con = true; change();">click me</button>
<script>
    window.con = false;
    function change() {
        while (window.con == true) {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;

            // Put some logic here to break the loop.
        }
       //do some more magical stuff
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank-you for your support.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend that approach. Not that it is not ok, but for the sake of having all code in the right places I would definitelly put all code in functions.

and - no offense - this coding practisies are a bit "old school", try to learn for example jQuery, and all the stuff will be hopefully much clearer then

Comment: jQuery doesn't solve all JS problems. For what you're talking about a simple `addEventListener` would do the trick. Isn't jQuery itself a bit old-school - it's older than 5 JS years which is like 120 in human years.

Comment: :) no, I am not talking about jQuery it self, but about coding approaches that for example jQuery uses. And because jQuery is maybe the most known and on web documented option, I chose to recommend it. And getting used to those approaches the OP can move further to any options and possibilities they're there....

Comment: *"Not that it is not ok"* - Actually it is *not* OK because it doesn't work: the OP's approach creates an infinite loop because Javascript is single-threaded so the loop condition can't be changed by another event handler while the loop is running.